# automatic browser zoom on load

Tags: jquery, html, css, zooming

Is it possible to set the browser zoom on a webpage I'm making to say 75% automatically on load with javascript? if so how can you do this?
I've googled but haven't really found anything.
thanks.

Comment: Why do you need the browser to zoom?

Comment: Just messing around seeing if it's possible to do

Comment: possible lie ^ but thanks for linking the page

Comment: A lie? how so? your title is "automatic browser zoom on load" and the linked question shows how to do that (I know, I wrote the accepted answer). If your question is significantly different, than you need to edit it to reflect that.

Comment: http://www.css3.com/css-zoom/

Comment: here we go.... Thanks for everyone who helped out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

and in CSS, make the `body { width:75%; margin:auto; }` to shrink content and center it.